# Как подключить js файл к проекту React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется страница с игрой и чтобы в нее поиграть нужно подключить game.js файл с логикой игры.
Game.jsx

```
import React from "react";
const Game = () => {
return(
    <div>
        <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <div type="button" id="green" className="btn green">
                </div>
                <div type="button" id="red" className="btn red">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div type="button" id="yellow" className="btn yellow">
                </div>
                <div type="button" id="blue" className="btn blue">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}
export default Game
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './style.css'
import './game.js'
import Game from "./pages/Game";
export default function App() {
return(
    <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
        <Route path="/scoreboard" element={<Scoreboard/>}>

        </Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<Game/>}>

        </Route>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>


)

}
```

index.html

```
  <body>

<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256- 
 H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Подключая файл через App.js появляется ошибка: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as game from './game.js'
```

тогда ты сможешь использовать функции из этого файла способом ниже:

```
game.someFunc()
```